# (R - an equivalence relation) if and only if R*R^-1 u I_A = R

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given relation $R:A\rightarrow A$
I need to prove that $R$ - equivalent relation $\iff (R\circ R^{-1}) \cup I_A = R$, where $I_A$ is an identity relation

My attempt:
$(R\circ R^{-1}) \cup I_A = R \iff {
\begin{cases} 
R \subset (R\circ R^{-1}) \cup I_A \\
(R\circ R^{-1}) \cup I_A \subset R
 \end{cases}} \iff
{\begin{cases} 
R \subset (R\circ R^{-1}) \cup I_A \\
(R\circ R^{-1}) \subset R \\
I_A \subset R
 \end{cases}}
$
Here I can already state that relation is reflexive. However, I have no clue how to show other two properties, namely symmetry and transitive.

Answer (score 1):

Facts: (i) $(R\circ S)^{-1}=S^{-1}\circ R^{-1}$, (ii) $(R^{-1})^{-1}=R$, (iii) $R\subseteq S\implies R^{-1}\subseteq S^{-1}$.

Then, by (i) and (ii), $(R\circ R^{-1})^{-1}=R\circ R^{-1}$ is symmetric; so is $I$, and the union of symmetric relations is symmetric.

It is given that $(R\circ R^{-1})\subseteq R$, hence by (iii), $(R\circ R^{-1})\subseteq R^{-1}$ as well. Thus
$$(R\circ R^{-1})\circ(R\circ R^{-1})\subseteq R\circ R^{-1}$$ which means transitivity of $R\circ R^{-1}$. It then follows easily that $(R\circ R^{-1})\cup I$ is also transitive.